# Fixed: How to make a moving character 3rd person in pygame,python and opengl?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opengl, pygame, trigonometry

So lately I've been starting to work on a 3rd person 3d mmorpg fantasy game, but I can't seem to work out the rotation and movement of the player depending on an amount of time. So what would I have to change in my code to to make the character rotate and then be able to walk or both at the same time in that direction.

I'm aiming for something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoxDDZmctnU and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-kuzyCkjoQ I tried to translate the code to python but it's not working, my player moves all over the place. Please help me.

Here is my code:

player class

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, model, engine):
        self.model = model
        self.engine = engine

        self.RUN_SPEED = 0.1
        self.TURN_SPEED = 0.6
        self.GRAVITY = -0.01
        self.JUMP_POWER = 2

        self.TERRAIN_HEIGHT = 0

        self.currentSpeed = 0
        self.currentTurnSpeed = 0
        self.upwardsSpeed = 0

        self.isInAir = False

        self.position = [0,0,0]
        self.rotation = [0,0,0]

    def move(self):
        Yrot               = 1.0 * (self.currentTurnSpeed * self.engine.getFrameTimeSeconds())       
        distance           = 1.0 * (self.currentSpeed * self.engine.getFrameTimeSeconds())
        self.upwardsSpeed += 1.0 * (self.GRAVITY * self.engine.getFrameTimeSeconds())
        dx = 1.0 * (distance * sin(Yrot+self.rotation[1]))
        dz = 1.0 * (distance * cos(Yrot+self.rotation[1]))

        self.increaseRotation(0,Yrot,0)
        self.increasePosition(dx, 0, dz)

        dy = 1.0 * (self.upwardsSpeed * self.engine.getFrameTimeSeconds())
        self.increasePosition(0, dy, 0)
        if self.position[1] < self.TERRAIN_HEIGHT:
            self.upwardsSpeed = 0
            self.position[1] = 0
            self.isInAir = False

    def jump(self):
        if not self.isInAir:
            self.upwardsSpeed = self.JUMP_POWER
            self.isInAir = True

    def render(self):
        self.model.draw(pos=self.position, rotations=self.rotation)

    def handleEvents(self, event):
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                self.currentSpeed = self.RUN_SPEED
            elif event.key == K_s:
                self.currentSpeed = -self.RUN_SPEED

            if event.key == K_a:
                self.currentTurnSpeed = self.TURN_SPEED
            elif event.key == K_d:
                self.currentTurnSpeed = -self.TURN_SPEED

            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                self.jump()

        else:
            self.currentSpeed = 0
            self.currentTurnSpeed = 0
    def increaseRotation(self,dx,dy,dz):
        self.rotation = [self.rotation[0]+dx,
                         self.rotation[1]+dy,
                         self.rotation[2]+dz]

    def increasePosition(self,dx,dy,dz):
        self.position = [self.position[0]+dx,
                         self.position[1]+dy,
                         self.position[2]+dz]
```

main.py, probably not necessary but just if anybody needs it to help understand my code to be able to help me ;) better safe than sorry

```
pygame.init()

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Screen = (800,600)

        self.Window = glLibWindow(self.Screen,caption="Test",multisample=True)
        self.View3D = glLibView3D((0,0,self.Screen[0],self.Screen[1]),65)
        self.View3D.set_view()

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        ### MAP ###
        Mesh = []
        heightmap = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("../data/map.png")).convert()
        for x in xrange(heightmap.get_width()):
            xrow = []
            for y in xrange(heightmap.get_height()):
                color = heightmap.get_at((x,y))
                height = color[0]*0.02
                xrow.append(height)
            Mesh.append(xrow)
        self.Map = glLibObjMap(Mesh,texturing=True,normals=GLLIB_VERTEX_NORMALS,heightscalar=20)
        self.MapTexture = glLibTexture(pygame.image.load("../data/map_texture.png"))
        self.Map.compile()

        self.campos = [0,-2,-20]
        self.player = Player(load_obj("../data/Player/kat_hood_up.obj"), self)

        self.lastFrameTime = self.getCurrentTime()
        self.delta = 0

    def loop(self):
        pygame.event.pump()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 4:
                    self.campos[2] -= 3
                if event.button == 5:
                    self.campos[2] += 3

            self.player.handleEvents(event)

        self.player.move()

        #Clear
        self.Window.clear()
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, (0,-20,0))

        #Position the camera
        self.View3D.set_view()

        glTranslatef(self.campos[0]+self.player.position[0],
                     self.campos[1]-self.player.position[1],
                     self.campos[2]+self.player.position[2])
        glTranslatef(*self.campos)
        glRotatef(180,0,1,0)

        self.player.render()
        self.Map.draw([0,0,0],[[0,150,0]])

        #Flip
        self.Window.flip()
        currentFrameTime = self.getCurrentTime()
        self.delta = (currentFrameTime - self.lastFrameTime)/1000
        self.lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime

    def getCurrentTime(self):
        return float(1000*pygame.time.get_ticks())
    def getFrameTimeSeconds(self):
        return float(self.delta)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        game.loop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I forgot to transform the self.rotation[1] to radians

```
dx = 1.0 * (distance * sin(radians(Yrot+self.rotation[1])))
dz = 1.0 * (distance * cos(radians(Yrot+self.rotation[1])))
```